# Whats wrong with my gradient descent?

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression

I am working on a simple linear regression but trying to optimize the MSE using tensorflow's gradient descent optimizer. However, the tensorflow code is not optimizing the MSE. The following is my code for trying to regress a line using GDOptimizer:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

#calculating MSE & beta_vec using stochastic gradient descent
X=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, name="X")
Y=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, name="Y")
X_test=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, name ="X_test")
Y_test=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, name ="Y_test")

beta_vec=tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=(9,1), dtype=tf.float64), dtype=tf.float64)
Y_pred = tf.matmul(X_test, beta_vec)
MSE = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(Y_pred, Y_test)))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)

def training_op():
    optimizer.minimize(MSE)
    return MSE

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    def fetch_rbatch():
        a=np.random.randint(0,len(traintarget))
        b=np.random.randint(0, len(traintarget))
        rbatch_trdata = traindata[min(a,b):max(a,b)]
        rbatch_trtarget=traintarget[min(a,b):max(a,b)]
        return rbatch_trdata, rbatch_trtarget
sess.run(init)
MSE, beta =sess.run((training_op(),beta_vec) ,feed_dict={X:fetch_rbatch()[0], Y:fetch_rbatch()[1], X_test:testdata, Y_test:testtarget})
print (MSE)
print (beta)
```

The result I am getting for my `MSE` and the `beta` is:

```
500900.504705
[[ 0.0637637 ]
 [ 0.71051187]
 [ 0.8872875 ]
 [ 0.11578163]
 [ 0.40620434]
 [ 0.76101558]
 [ 0.17046824]
 [ 0.59776537]
 [ 0.43706391]]
```

The `MSE` is just the value returned by doing tensorflow operation with the uniformly randomly generated `beta_vec`. There isnt any GDOptimization on MSE being performed at all. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: `training_op` looks a little strange, since it returns a global variable. Wouldn't it be easier to call `minimize` directly after initializing `optimizer`? And then `sess.run` should take `(optimizer, beta_vec)` as first argument.

Comment: Would it make a difference? I used the function `training_op()` so that it can output me the most minimized `MSE` since if I call `optimize.mse` directly and then call `MSE.eval()` inside the `tf.Session` it would return an error on the `MSE.eval()` saying that the tensors in my `feed_dict` are empty, which is why I used `training_op` as a function so that it can do `optimizer.minimize` on my `MSE` and return the most minimized `MSE` as well within the same line of code inside my `tf.Session`

Answer (score 0):

A little refactored, but still no clue about your `traintarget` and co:

```
def fetch_rbatch():
    a = np.random.randint(0, len(traintarget))
    b = np.random.randint(0, len(traintarget))
    rbatch_trdata = traindata[min(a, b):max(a, b)]
    rbatch_trtarget = traintarget[min(a, b):max(a, b)]
    return rbatch_trdata, rbatch_trtarget


def main():
    X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, name="X")
    Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, name="Y")
    X_test = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, name="X_test")
    Y_test = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, name="Y_test")

    beta_vec = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=(9, 1), dtype=tf.float64), dtype=tf.float64)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(X, Y)))  # aka MSE, note that loss calculated on train data
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(loss)  # merge with minimizer
    # Y_pred = tf.matmul(X_test, beta_vec)
    # todo for @mkdar: make accuracy op

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()  # init vars
        for i in range(1000):  # number of steps
            # note underscore in loss, and that we pass optimiser in order to train stuff
            loss_, beta, _ = sess.run([loss, beta_vec, optimizer],
                                      feed_dict={
                                        X: fetch_rbatch()[0],
                                        Y: fetch_rbatch()[1],
                                        X_test: testdata,  # useless coz we do nothing
                                        Y_test: testtarget})  # this too
            if i % 20 == 19:
                # print every 20 step
                print(loss_)
                print(beta)
```

also check out [official tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners) if you are new

Comment: `traintarget` is just a target vector that is used for training